# How to find a maximum distance between any point on a circle and a ellipse?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

$P$ satisfies $x^2+(y-4)^2=1$, and $Q$ satisfies $\frac{x^2}{4}+y^2=1$. What is the maximum value of $|PQ|$?

I tried to solve this graphically, but can't sure whether the maximum that I saw is the correct one. What I could see based on the diagram, max of $|PQ|$ is 6, but could it be possible that there is a greater value then 6?

[image]

I also thought of differentiation, but the $|PQ|$ function has too many variables. $|PQ|=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$

Any ideas to solve this by calculation? Thanks

Comment: When you say the points are "moving", the nature of the motion is potentially relevant, which means you would have to _define_ the motions.

Comment: @achille hui sorry for the mistake of equation, just corrected that.

Comment: @quasi the question itself didn't mention about the motions, I guess it means that P or Q is any point on the curve

Comment: Possibly the term "movable" (instead of "moving") could've been used to be more clear. (Although saying P is on the circle and Q is on the ellipse would've been clearer still.)  A formula you could differentiate would be $|PQ|=\sqrt{(0-x)^2+\left(6+\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{4}}\right)^2}$, because you know $(0,6)$ is farthest point on circle and you know that given an $x$ what the corresponding farthest $y$ value on the ellipse is (it will be negative).

Comment: Hint: If the [eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)) of the ellipse is greater than a certain value, then the max of $|PQ| > 6$.

Comment: @Χpẘ According to the given ellipse, the eccentricity is $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$. I wonder is there a way to solve this using formula or theorem related to conic section? (since it has been solved using differentiation)

Comment: Oops, the furthest point on circle is $(0,5)$. I mistakenly said $(0,6)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $P,Q$ are points, with $P$ on the circle, and $Q$ on the ellipse, such that the distance from $P$ to $Q$ is maximized. Let $w = d(P,Q)$.

From the geometry, it's clear that $P$ must be on the upper half of the circle, and $Q$ must be on the lower half of the ellipse.

As a necessary condition, the line segment $PQ$ must be perpendicular to the circle at the point $P$. It follows that the segment $PQ$ must pass through the center of the circle.
Hence, since the radius of the circle is $1$, we must have$\;w=v+1$, where $v$ is the maximum possible distance from the center of the circle,$\;(0,4),\;$to a point $Q$ on the ellipse.

Maximizing the square of the distance will make the job easier$\,-\,$we can take the square root of the result later.

Let $Q=(x,y)$.

By symmetry, we can assume $x \ge 0$, and from the geometry, we must have $-1 \le y \le 0$.

Then $x,y$ are such that
$$x^2 + (y-4)^2$$
is maximized, subject to the constraint
$$\frac{x^2}{4}+y^2=1$$
Replacing $x^2$ by $4-4y^2$, you want to maximize
$$f(y) = (4-4y^2) + (y-4)^2$$
subject to the constraint $-1 \le y \le 0$.

So the problem is reduced to a one-variable maximization of a quadratic polynomial on a closed interval.

Can you finish it?

After you find the maximum value of $f$ on the interval $[-1,0]$, don't forget to take the square root (since we maximized the square of the distance to the center of the circle), and finally, remember that to get the final answer, we have to add $1$ (the radius of the circle).

As it turns out, the final answer, as anticipated, is $6$, with the obvious points $P,Q$, but if you change the term ${\large{\frac{x^2}{4}}}$ to ${\large{\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}$, for some fixed $a > \sqrt{5}$, then using the same solution method as outlined above, the point $Q$ will be on the lower half of the ellipse, but *not* at a vertex, so the final answer would then be greater than $6$.

Comment: from $f'(y)=0$, I got $y=\frac{-4}{3}$. Then I got $f(\frac{-4}{3})=25\frac{1}{3}$. Then by square rooting this value, I get 5.03322.... By adding 1 to it, then I get 6.03322... Is this correct?

Comment: but $-1\le y\le0$, so I wonder this is correct

Comment: The interval for $y$ is $[-1,0]$, so the maximum occurs at $y=-1$. That gives $Q=(0,-1)$ and $P=(0,5)$, with a distance of $6$. As I indicated, the problem is more interesting if $x^2/4$ is changed to $x^2/a^2$, where $a > \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Thank you very much.The answer is the same with the way (using differentiation) suggested by @Xpw on the comment above.

Comment: $(0,5)$ is _not_ the furthest point on the circle if $a > \sqrt{5}$, Try the case $a=\sqrt{6}$ both ways. In other words, use the same circle, but change the ellipse to 
$$\frac{x^2}{6}+y^2=1$$
and compare the methods. The answers won't agree.

Comment: I was wondering since early whether (0,5) is the furthest point from the ellipse. So by what you mentioned, (0,5) is the furthest point ONLY when $a\le \sqrt{5}$?

Comment: Right, it's the furthest point ONLY when $a \le \sqrt{5}$. Thus, Xpw intuited that $(0,5)$ was furthest, and got lucky!

Comment: As a challenge, assume $a > \sqrt{5}$, but leave it unknown. In terms of $a$, find the maximum value of $d(P,Q)$.

Comment: When $0 < a \le \sqrt{5}$, the maximum value of $d(P,Q)$ is exactly $6$, and $P,Q$ must be $(0,5),\;(0,-1)$, respectively. If $a > \sqrt{5}$, the maximum value of $d(P,Q)$ will be greater than $6$, and the point $(0,5)$ will not be one of the two choices for $P$.

Comment: @Quasi you're right, I didn't take into account that the distance could be maximized if $a > \sqrt{6}$ (not $\sqrt{5}$). I wasn't lucky, just not observant. Here is a interactive of the problem: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zhtkhtwg3n. The purple point can be moved anywhere, but should be on circle to follow constraint of problem. The red curve shows the distance of the point to the bottom half of the ellipse. You'll notice it is concave if $a \le \sqrt{6}$. As $a$ gets bigger then there is a "dip" in the curve where it intersect $x=0$. Orange curve is derivative of distance curve.

Comment: @Xpw: Unless I made an error, what I get is this: 
$$$$
If $0 < a \le \sqrt{5}$, the maximum value of $d(P,Q)$ is equal to $6$, with $P=(0,5)$ and $Q=(0,-1)$..
$$$$
If $a > \sqrt{5}$, the maximum value of $d(P,Q)$ is greater than $6$, with two distinct points $P$, symmetrical about the y-axis, and in particular, $P \ne (0,5)$.

Comment: @Xpw: When I said you got "lucky", what I meant is that without actually doing the maximization. you had no justification for the assumption that $P=(0,5)$ was optimal for $P$. In fact, it _is_ optimal since $a = 2 \le \sqrt{5}$, but that's essentially just a fortunate accident, based on the specific choice of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem in the complex plane as follows: recognizing that the solution must rest in the upper part of the circle and lower half of the ellipse, we can write

$$
z_c=e^{i\theta},\quad \theta\in[0,\pi]\\
\begin{align}
z_e
&=2\cos \theta+i\sin\theta,\quad \theta\in[\pi,2\pi]\\
&=-2\cos \theta-i\sin\theta,\quad \theta\in[0,\pi]\\
\end{align}
$$

Then,

$$
\begin{align}
|z_c-z_e|
&=|\cos\theta+i(\sin\theta+4)-(-2\cos \theta-i\sin\theta)|\\
&=|3\cos\theta+i(2\sin\theta+4)|\\
&=\sqrt{9\cos^2\theta+4\sin^2\theta+16\sin\theta+16}\\
&=\sqrt{5\cos^2\theta+16\sin\theta+20}\\
\end{align}
$$

We can now optimize by setting

$$\frac{d}{d\theta}|z_c-z_e|=\frac{1}{2}\frac{-10\cos\theta\sin\theta+16\cos\theta}{\sqrt{5\cos^2\theta+16\sin\theta+20}}=0$$

The possible solutions are

$$
\sin\theta=\frac{16}{10},\quad \text{impossible}\\
\cos\theta=0,\quad \text{max value at } \theta=\pi/2\\
$$

In other words, from the top of the circle to the bottom of the ellipse, with $|z_c-z_e|=\sqrt{5\cos^2\theta+16\sin\theta+20}=\sqrt{36}=6$.